# User Profile synchronization connection has been deleted but still user profiles show up in SharePoint

Tags: user-profile-service, synchronization

We have SharePoint 2013 environment and we have 2 AD connections (ie. 2 different domains) in User Profile Service Application. All the users from DomainA have been moved to DomainB and AD team have created new user accounts for these users. Now I want to delete the old user accounts of DomainA. So , I went ahead and deleted the DomainA connection and ran a full synchronization and this did not resolve my issue. As domainA users still show up in SharePoint.

AD Import is the synchronization method we are using to import users from AD.

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need run full sync few times and in FIM look for flags for deletion. SP will delete users after few full sync.

Read this msdn blog how user profile and sync works.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2012/06/25/inside-the-sharepoint-2010-my-site-cleanup-timer-job/

Comment: Hi, AD Import is the synchronization method we use so FIM does not come into picture here. My site clean up job is also enabled on the server. Also we have run the Full import multiple times already :)